# Bound DataGridView Columns: read only + Default Value

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridview, default-value

I bound a datagridview to a local database.

The table I am displaying in the DGV has the following columns:

- ID Number (int): basically the row number incremeted automatocally
- Current value (real)
- Unit of current (nvarchar) : mA : this one I would like it to appear automatically in the column when a new row is started : so read only and default value as mA
- Time value (int)
- time unit (nvarchar) :in seconds
- Index (int)

I designed the table containing these elements and bound it to the grid.

**Goal**

When a new row is generated, I would like to see in the columns :

Unit I ===> mA
Unit T ===> s

So the columns should be read-only and have a default value of repectively mA and s

**found**

- the defaulValue property : [DefaultValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.defaultvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

and

```
    dgrid.Columns["colName"].ReadOnly = true;
```

I would like to know how to achieve this combination. Is the programming done on the datatable or on the datagridview and how ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If data is being added by people in a DGV you could supply those values when a new row is added.  `NewRowNeeded` and/or `DefaultValuesNeeded`  might work depending on how rows are added

Comment: even with a bound DGV? As I bound the DGV programmatically, I probably can't name the colums before they are loaded , right ? And yes the data is input by the user.